# Add first page and last page Buttons in DataGridView paging

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Im using this code to add paging to a `Datagridview`.
What I want is how can I add Button to go to the first page and another Button to go to the last page??

This is the code:

```
Imports System.Data.Odbc ' using ODBC namespace

Public Class Form1
    Dim conn As OdbcConnection ' declare for our connection
    Dim Da As OdbcDataAdapter ' declare for Data Adapter
    Dim Ds As DataSet ' declare for dataset
    Dim Filter As Integer ' for max value to show the data/paging 

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ' load data button
        ' you must have a Database before
        ' i use MySQL database for this application
        ' i'll create connection using Odbc
        ' set connection using ODBC
        conn = New OdbcConnection("DSN=k13new;MultipleActiveResultSets=True")
        ' create SQL query to show data from MySQL Database
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM biodata order by idsiswa"
        Da = New OdbcDataAdapter(sql, conn)
        Ds = New DataSet

        ' open connection
        conn.Open()
        Da.Fill(Ds, Filter, 15, "biodata")
        ' max Count of data will show at one page is 15
        ' close connection
        conn.Close()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Ds
        DataGridView1.DataMember = "biodata"
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        ' prev button
        Filter = Filter - 15
        If Filter <= 0 Then
            Filter = 0
        End If
        Ds.Clear()
        Da.Fill(Ds, Filter, 15, "biodata")
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        ' next button
        Filter = Filter + 15
        Ds.Clear()
        Da.Fill(Ds, Filter, 15, "biodata")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If it is VB.NET it cant be access-vba, same if you are using a DataGridView

Comment: @Plutonix yes, it was mistake, I edit it thank you.

Comment: Wouldnt the first page just be `0, 15`?  The only way to do a last page is to know the last Ids.  To do that you could load all the Ids at the outset, chop them into `First, Last` sets and make an actual  *`Go To Page n`*- version

Comment: @Plutonix I'll try it thank you.